# Comparison of image RGB in python

Tags: python, colors, histogram, jpeg, rgb

I have 5 images and I have created histograms of the RGB values in each image using PILLOW. I would like to compare the RGB values and distributions within each of the 5 images to see if they are different or the same.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to do this since I am new to python and I can see there are some complex answers to similar questions on here but if there was something very simple to do this this would be great.

I do not need to know if the RGB code is the same for the same pixel in each image, just the overall distribution of colours and the amount they occur in.

Thanks

Comment: You can do Z Test

Comment: This is relatively simple and effective https://mpatacchiola.github.io/blog/2016/11/12/the-simplest-classifier-histogram-intersection.html